# Using a method to create an array then using that array in the main method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to use this array I create in printGrid method throughout my program. Currently, I have to run this method, but the values change because of the math.random method nested in this method and I don't want it to. I just want to run this once and use the output throughout my method, is this possible?

What I've tried - I've tried to return the value of the mapArray (seen in code) and printing that out, I'm having issue with that. I've also tried isolating the math.random method in it's own method to calculate the value of the cookies, but my issue with that is that it only returns one value and I need a dynamic amount depending on the input of the x / y vars. Any suggestions?

```
public static char[][] printGrid(int x, int y) {
    // int [][] mapArray = new int [x][y];      // Gets the information to print the array

    mapArray = new char[x][y]; // Gets the information to print the array
    double cookies = (x * y) * (.1); // Calculates the number of cookies per x / y  input

    // Storing '.' in all values of the array
    for (int d = 0; d < x; d++) // Moved from below. 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            mapArray[d][j] = '.';
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    // Storing '0' in random values of the array and '<' at [0][0]
    int c = 0;
    for (c = 1; c <= cookies; c++) {

        int cookiesPrintColumn = (int)(cookies * Math.random());
        int cookiesPrintRow = (int)(cookies * Math.random());

        mapArray[cookiesPrintColumn][cookiesPrintRow] = 'O';
        mapArray[0][0] = '>';
    }

    // Copy loop from above to print the grid.
    for (int d = 0; d < x; d++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            System.out.print(mapArray[d][j]);
            return mapArray;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
    return mapArray;
} // printGrid method close
```

Comment: Remove the return statement from the middle of your printing loop.

Comment: Roger, just did. It's compiling just fine, but how would I print that in the main method?

Answer (score 0):

Use return value:

```
import package.ClassNane;
class Example {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    char[][] grid = ClassName.printGrid(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think you're missing the question. I have the correct variables made and already put into the array. . .it's displaying correctly, I just need to know how to use it out of the method it's created in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create an array in a method, and then need to use in throughout your program, such as in main, you aren't going to be able to directly use that exact array because it will be out of scope. You can however create and then initialize the array in main equal to the return statement of your method. For example:

```
main() {
int[][] example;
example[][] = method(...);
}

int [][] method(...){
int[][] exampleArray = {1,2,3} // your random values here
return exampleArray;
}
```

Because you are creating the actual array inside of the method, it will not be in scope in main. This however will have the exact values the same, so the random numbers will be identical, and you can continue to use this for the rest of your program.

Comment: Chris, Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. What you're describing is exactly what I want to accomplish, but I'm not understanding your code. My code above already creates the proper array, but it only does when I call the method. Could you explain how I could get that array out of the method it's in and in the main method?

Comment: So, in your actual main method, your create an array. Don't assign it anything in particular, i.e. myArray[][]; After than, you should be able to assign "myArray" equal to the call of the method. I.e. myArray = printGrid(int x, int y). So, in essence, the actual return value from "printGrid" is returning a 2d array, which "myArray" will then point to. This will keep it in scope of your main, and you can continue to use "myArray" as if it were the array you created in "printGrid"